# Set world space canvas to VR camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am trying to make a canvas that covers the whole view of the Google Cardboard user. I have the following script to set the canvas to the height of the left eye camera's fov. This works correctly in the editor view.

```
float camHeight = 2.0f * distanceToCamera * Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad * (eyeCam.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView * 0.5f));
float scaleSet = (camHeight / canvasRectTransform.rect.height);
transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleSet, scaleSet, scaleSet);
```

But when I test this in Android (Galaxy S6), the canvas is too small.

How can I scale the canvas to the total view of the user?

Comment: Select the Canvas GameObject in the hierarchy -> Canvas Scaler (Script) component -> Change the Screen Match Mode to Match Width Or Height. Is it OK for you, or you need to do it in the script?

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I need to use a World Space canvas for a VR app. So two camera's. The canvas scaler does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a HUD, simply parent the world space canvas to the VR Camera Game Object (or center eye camera if you have one) and scale it manually in the editor until it is the size you want. Make sure it's positioned at least 0.5m-2m away for stereoscopy.

The FOV is different over different phones so use the area within 80% of the center view to be safe.